# Show preview of taken picture but without editing UIImagePickerController UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to show a preview if someone selects a photo from his libary.

My code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self; 
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePickerController.allowsImageEditing = NO;

        [[self parentViewController] presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
        [imagePickerController release];
```

If i set allowsImageEditing = YES, it show a preview (like the one I want), but I can edit the photo (shrink/cut). I just would like that the user has the option to cancel or to confirm the selecting photo, like the preview when you take a new picture (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera).

I would like the preview like its on the right side:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and show a customized preview in UIImagePickerController 's delegate class 's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.  get Image from

```
originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

The show it in a ImageView.

also need set UIImagePickerController.showsCameraControls=NO.